# Make a sticky scrollable sidebar with no styles applied through JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

[That's how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khX1G.png). I saw this sidebar some time ago and was able to find [the page in the web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20181205020515/https://tjournal.ru/).

When you scroll down the page, the sidebar scrolls too and sticks to the bottom. When you scroll up, even if you're somewhere in the middle of the page, the sidebar scrolls up too.

This solution is fairly simple and doesn't apply any CSS while the sidebar is working. Some kind of magic using initial CSS like full viewport height, sticky positioning, hidden overflow and JS like scrollTop.

I managed to pull out the part of the source code that's responsible for the sidebar, but I can't understand how it works. This function seems to be responsible for such behavior:

```
function(e, t) {
  Air.define(
    'module.sticky_sidebar',
    'lib.DOM, module.DOM, module.metrics, module.propaganda, module.notify, module.smart_ajax',
    function(e, t, n, i, o, r) {
      var a,
        s,
        l,
        c = this,
        u = 0,
        d = !1,
        h = function() {
          var t = s.scrollTop,
            i = Math.round(e.rect(a).top)
          50 === i
            ? (s.scrollTop = t + (n.scroll_top - u))
            : i > 50
            ? (s.scrollTop = 0)
            : i < 50 && (s.scrollTop = 999999),
            (u = n.scroll_top)
        },
        f = function() {
          a && s && e.bem.toggle(a, 'height_auto', !(n.window_height - 50 < s.scrollHeight))
        },
        m = function(t) {
          if (((5 != t && 3 != t) || (l[t] = !1), !1 === l[5] && !1 === l[3])) {
            var n = e.find('.page--entry')
            n && (e.toggleClass(n, 'with--entry_center', !0), c.destroy()), (n = null)
          }
        }
      ;(c.init = function() {
        ;(a = c.elements[0].element),
          (s = e.find(a, '.sticky_sidebar__scroll')),
          (l = {
            5: !0,
            3: !0
          }),
          n.on('Breakpoint changed', function(e) {
            'wide' === e || 'desktop' === e
              ? !1 === d &&
                n.document_height - 20 > n.window_height &&
                (t.on('Window scroll', h), t.on('Window resize', f), f(), (d = !0))
              : !0 === d && (t.off(), (d = !1))
          })
      }),
        (c.refresh = function() {
          c.destroy(), c.init()
        }),
        (c.destroy = function() {
          t.off(), n.off(), i.off(), (u = 0), (a = s = null), (d = !1)
        })
    }
  )
}
```

And the CSS:

```
.sticky_sidebar {
  top: 50px;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: sticky;
}
.sticky_sidebar__scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: Asking people to help you decipher minified code is a bit much -- is there a specific part of it that you need help understanding?

Comment: @JonWarren I can't understand the JS part, how it works in combination with these styles. Probably some simple calculations with scroll heights.

Comment: The problem with the code that you provided is that it's minified, which has obfuscated the code. Do you have a non-minified version of the code that you can reference?

Comment: @JonWarren The function above has a lot of unnecessary code, that's for sure. I was not sure what could be removed. Unfortunately, only minified code. :(

Comment: Simply search online for 'css sticky sidebar' and start from scratch . There are plenty examples to find (found 10 myself just yet). As mentioned by other commenters, this one isn't going to bring you joy anytime soon...